# How get user profile link of facebook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook, react-native-fbsdk

I am using [react-native-fbsdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk) and tried to get data of user while user is logging in my app using facebook.
I am able to get name,first_name,last_name,email and picture but I also want profile link of user profile of facebook.
I have permssion of `user_link`.

Can someone explain where I am going or what I need to get the profile url.

```
         LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['email', 'public_profile', 'user_link'])
        .then(
            login => {
             AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
             const accessToken = data.accessToken.toString();accessToken);
             this.getInfoFromToken(accessToken);
                    });
         })

 getInfoFromToken = token => {
    const PROFILE_REQUEST_PARAMS = {
        fields: {
            string: 'id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture',
        },
    };
    const profileRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        { token, parameters: PROFILE_REQUEST_PARAMS },
        (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                //this.setState({ userInfo: error }, () => this.getData())
                console.log('login info has error: ' + error);

            } else {
                this.setState({ userInfo: user }, () => 
                console.log('result:', user);
            }
        },
    );
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(profileRequest).start();
};
```

Comment: _"I am able to get name,first_name,last_name,email and picture"_ - and how where you able to get those, might that be related to `string: 'id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture'` perhaps ...? Well then you should know what to do.

Comment: I tried `link` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well then I'd guess that your user token does not actually contain the `user_link` permission. Have you debugged the token to verify that?

Comment: yes you are right. I have permissions of `email` and `public_profile`. Thank you!!!